# Is this return statement in the _.delay function of underscore.js extraneous?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

This is the code for `_.delay`:

```
// Delays a function for the given number of milliseconds, and then calls
// it with the arguments supplied.
_.delay = function(func, wait) {
  var args = slice.call(arguments, 2);
  return setTimeout(function() {
    return func.apply(null, args);
  }, wait);
};
```

The first `return` statement before `setTimeout` is definitely useful because it returns the `timeoutID` that can be used to cancel the timer. No question there.

However, I do not see how the `return` statement within the function *passed* to `setTimeout` can have any effect since `setTimeout` is asynchronous. Is that inner `return` statement extraneous?

In order to access that asynchronous result, a promise or similar construct would need to be registered.

`underscore.js` is a well-polished library that tries to limit its number of bytes; so, it seems strange that such an extraneous statement would be present.

Comment: This looks like future proofing to me incase setTimeout someday returns a promise for async/await operations. Speculation though.

Comment: Interesting. Could be for readability. An explicit signal that "this function should end here". How do they handle other situations that don't require a function's return value?

Comment: @tscizzle, within `_.debounce` and `_.throttle`, there are `later` functions that do not return anything.

Comment: Well considering `setTimeout` currently does not return a promise, I'm going with future proofing, explicitness, or extraneous.

Comment: @KyleRichardson, Interesting thought! :) As a side note: Some promise implementations actually use `setTimeout` internally with a wait of `0` so that handlers passed to `.then` or `.done` are executed only after the next tick. This could also be done with `process.nextTick`.

Comment: @KyleRichardson I agree. You're three possibilities seem to cover everything.