# Attaching an attribute to a Promise

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

Another question on SO perked my interest in creating a `setTimeout` that returned a Promise and a timerId, yet would not break backwards compatibility. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45260518/is-this-return-statement-in-the-delay-function-of-underscore-js-extraneous?noredirect=1#comment77484944_45260518) is the question I am referring to.

It simply asks if the inner return statement in the `_.delay` method of `underscore.js` is extraneous or serves a purpose. Here is the block of code.

This is the code for _.delay:

```
// Delays a function for the given number of milliseconds, and then calls
// it with the arguments supplied.
_.delay = function(func, wait) {
    var args = slice.call(arguments, 2);
    return setTimeout(function() { // this is to return the timerId
        return func.apply(null, args); // this guy right is in question
    }, wait);
};
```

Considering setTimeout does not currently return a Promise, I proposed the idea that it is possibly there for future proofing, incase setTimeout does one day return a promise.

To do this `setTimeout` would need to return a timerId so that it can be canceled. So to return a `Promise` you would need to attach the timerId to the Promise, so that the Promise is returned and the timerId is accessable.

You could then modify `clearTimeout` to perform exactly how it does now when given a timerId, but for a Promise it uses Promise.timerId to clear the timeout and cancel the Promise. *Of course Promise canceling would need to be implemented as well...*

Anyhow... I started working on something for fun and came across something I haven't been able to explain. If you run the snippet below, you will see that the promise has `.timerId` attribute before it is returned, but the attribute is missing after the return. Can anyone explain this?

```js
function pseudoSetTimeout( func, wait ) {

    let timerId,
        promise = new Promise( ( resolve, reject ) => {
            timerId = setTimeout( () => {
                let returnVal = func();
                resolve( returnVal );
            }, wait );
        });

    promise.timerId = timerId;

    console.log( "promise before return: ", promise );

    return promise;
}

function callback() {
    return "Callback fired";
}

let timeout = pseudoSetTimeout( callback, 1000 )
    .then( ( val ) => {
      console.log( val );
    });

console.log( "returned promise: ", timeout );
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `then` in:

```
pseudoSetTimeout( callback, 1000 )
    .then( ( val ) => {
      console.log( val );
    });
```

returns a new promise, which is not the one that `pseudoSetTimeout` returned. It is a promise with `undefined` as promised value, since the `then` callback does not return anything.

You could make it work by not applying `then` during the assignment:

```js
function pseudoSetTimeout( func, wait ) {

    let timerId,
        promise = new Promise( ( resolve, reject ) => {
            timerId = setTimeout( () => {
                let returnVal = func();
                resolve( returnVal );
            }, wait );
        });

    promise.timerId = timerId;

    console.log( "promise before return: ", promise );

    return promise;
}

function callback() {
    return "Callback fired";
}

let timeout = pseudoSetTimeout( callback, 1000 );
timeout.then( ( val ) => {
  console.log( val );
});

console.log( "returned promise: ", timeout );
```

Because `then` is crucial in the use of promises, and is often used in chaining them, it seems that the idea to attach a custom property to a promise loses on usefulness.

Comment: Thank you sir! That is one thing I had obviously not tried and I learned something new today! Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Really interesting question.

Not sure of how it's made internally in node, but if looking on the then code of bluebird is any indication : https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/src/thenables.js

My guess would be that the Promise returned is actually another object.

Comment: You are correct that it is another promise. If you're interested, @trincot provided a great answer.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the reasons mentioned in the other answers, I would return a 'tuple' instead of using a property on the promise:

```js
function pseudoSetTimeout( func, wait ) {
    let timerId,
        promise = new Promise( ( resolve, reject ) => {
            timerId = setTimeout( () => {
                let returnVal = func();
                resolve( returnVal );
            }, wait );
        });

    let result = [timerId, promise];
    console.log ( "returning: ", result );
    return result;
}

function callback() {
    return "Callback fired";
}

let [timeout, promise] = pseudoSetTimeout( callback, 1000 );

promise.then( ( val ) => {
   console.log( val );
});

console.log( "returned timeout: ", timeout );
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I had thought of and tried this, and decided it was not the way to go because it would break backwards compatibility if a new version of `setTimeout` returned a tuple.

Comment: @KyleRichardson I wouldn't expect `setTimeout` to change. If it does change, it will already break all code that holds on to the `timerID`. (I suppose if they made a symmetrical change to `clearTimeout` and you didn't do anything fancy with the timerID, it might not break. But then the tuple would not break either.) But even then, your `pseudoSetTimeout` function is already the best thing to do about that: wrap the usage of `setTimeout` in a method and hide the implementation, returning what you need. If `setTimeout` changes, then you have only this one place to update.

Comment: that is why I mentioned `clearTimeout` would need updated. It's true that if you did something with timerId other than pass it to clearTimeout, it would be breaking.